# CoreData: Find minimum of calculated property

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Say I have a CoreData entity "Point" with two properties x and y (both NSNumber).

How would a NSPredicate need to look like to let me find the closest Point to say a,b?
for distance = sqrt((x-a)*(x-a)+(y-b)*(y-b))

While I could define a transient property that calculates a distance to a predefined point I can't see how I could programmatically change that point when launching a fetchrequest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but doing arithmetic in an `NSPredicate` isn't supported. Only comparison operators can be used. And the news gets worse. You can't use a transient property in an `NSFetchRequest`. Only persistent properties can be used. If you really need this level of control in fetching your objects, Core Data may not be able to accommodate you.

Comment: Thanks again Alex. This saved me some time trying to find a way when there is none. I will fetch a set of points around the point and then find the closest based on that subset (with a wide enough margin, that should yield the desired result)