# What is the fastest way to sort a lot of locations on distance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, core-location

I want to sort lots of locations (waypoints) on their distance from the current location.
The current location is, of course, a moving target, so for every location update, recomputing the distance for every location is necessary. But only recomputing for close-by locations would by enough.

I currently use core-data, and store the distance to the current location as an attribute in the table (but only update is when it is changed) from within the configurecell: atindexpath: method.
That sort of works, but the application is not responding while core-data automagically is updating all distances. This works for 250 locations, but for 5000 it crashes.
I need it to work for 10.000 locations, although I probably only need the 1000 closest locations or so.

Ideas that I did not try yet:
Store all distances in a separate in-memory array with nothing but record id and distance. Then sort the array on distance. Problem is that then I can not use a FetchedResultsController because there is no sort field in the database.

Filter locations based on their latitude and longitude by using a predicate. Then only present the filtered locations.

Do the recalculation of distances in a separate thread.

None of the ideas seems easy enough to just try it out.

Anybody with suggestions, different ideas, a variation on my ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final solution is as follows:
I select all waypoints within 1 degree latitude and longitude (about 1000 waypoints normally) and then compute and store the distance to the current position in the table. I can then sort on the distance. The slow thing would be the saving in Core Data. But after sorting (and fetching), I simply cancel the changes. The saving was taking more than 90 % of the whole thing, so this worked quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to convert your locations to positions on a Hilbert curve - then points "near" you are a simple subtraction?

[Mapping N-dimensional value to a point on Hilbert curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499166/mapping-n-dimensional-value-to-a-point-on-hilbert-curve)

Can't say I know the technique inside out, but that's where I'd start to look

Comment: For this I need a "Centre location". so I can treat all locations as points on a flat surface. I think this is suited to 'pre-sort' all locations, so that nearby locations are pre sorted nearby. And all my locations would be in Europe for now. It might be part of the solution.

Comment: Hilbert Curve is certainly "the" way to do it, but if my understanding of space filling curves is correct, any space filling curve will do (Peano comes to mind. Chose one that preserves locality well though). Another thing to consider is storing your locations in an adaptive kd-tree to quickly rule out locations too distant away.

Comment: For low dimensions, kd-tree is better than space filling curve. For high dimensions, it is only good if N >= 2^D (N = number of points, D = dimensions). The reason is that if you split along a different dimension for each level in the kd-tree, if you have too few points, you will have a single point in each leaf before you have split along every dimension. This means that the tree structure ignores the remaining dimensions and quality suffers.

Answer (score 1):

If what's important is the order (as opposed to having accurate distances), you could sort slices of the waypoint sequence in a moving window (that is, sort items *i* to *i+n*, where *i* changes). Start at the beginning of the waypoint sequence. Sort *n* items (n = 10 is a good place to start). If any items changed position, move the window forward by *n/2* (experiment with different offsets or algorithms to choose an offset) and repeat. Depending on how dense the waypoint are near the current location, I would expect this to stop after only a few sorts.

Note that I haven't thought about this long enough to say whether or not this will actually work.

Of the three options you mention, I like using threads the most. That's the classical way of handling a non-responsive UI when it's blocked by heavy computation.

Comment: I now think my strategy will be: Mark a small 'square' part of the map with the current position in center and find all waypoints in this area. Like described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176127/core-data-and-core-location/2176193#2176193 
If I have enough waypoints to my liking, I stop. If not enough, I double the range (getting 4 x as many area to cover) and repeat.
By doing this in the background, the UI stays responsive.
Lastly, if a new position update comes in, I start over with a small bounding box.

Comment: You could post that as an answer. Maybe you'll get a self-learner badge.

Answer (score 0):

I store my locations in the data model as latitude/longitude coordinates.  Then I wrote some helper extensions to find a semirectangular region of lat/lon coordinates and query by that.  Here's the code I'm using.  I know the question was for Objective-C but the question is old and likely most people are looking for a Swift answer anyway now.

**Swift 3**

```
   extension CLLocationDistance {
        var feet: Double {
            return self * 3.28084
        }
        var miles: Double {
            return self.feet / 5280.0
        }
    }

    extension CLLocationDegrees {
        static var north: CLLocationDegrees {
            return 90.0
        }
        static var south: CLLocationDegrees {
            return -90.0
        }
        static var east: CLLocationDegrees {
            return 180.0
        }
        static var west: CLLocationDegrees {
            return -180.0
        }

        var radians: Double {
            return Double.pi * self / 180.0
        }
    }

    extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        static var origin: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
        }

        static var northPole: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90.0, longitude: 0.0)
        }

        static var southPole: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90.0, longitude: 0.0)
        }

        var metersPerDegreeLatitude: CLLocationDistance {
            return 111319.4907932736
        }
        var metersPerDegreeLongitude: CLLocationDistance {
            return max(0.0, cos(self.latitude.radians) * self.metersPerDegreeLatitude)
        }
    }

    extension CLCircularRegion {
        var northernmostLatitude: CLLocationDegrees {
            let longitude = self.center.latitude + self.radius / self.center.metersPerDegreeLatitude
            return min(longitude, .north)
        }

        var southernmostLatitude: CLLocationDegrees {
            let longitude = self.center.latitude - self.radius / self.center.metersPerDegreeLatitude
            return max(longitude, .south)
        }

        var easternmostLongitude: CLLocationDegrees {
            guard self.northernmostLatitude <= .north else {
                return .east
            }
            guard self.southernmostLatitude >= .south else {
                return .east
            }
            return min(.east, self.center.longitude + self.radius / (self.center.metersPerDegreeLongitude + 0.0001))
        }

        var westernmostLongitude: CLLocationDegrees {
            guard self.northernmostLatitude <= .north else {
                return .west
            }
            guard self.southernmostLatitude >= .south else {
                return .west
            }
            return max(.west, self.center.longitude - self.radius / (self.center.metersPerDegreeLongitude + 0.0001))
        }

        func buildPredicate(latitudeName: String = "latitude", longitudeName: String = "longitude") -> NSPredicate {
            let args = [self.southernmostLatitude, self.northernmostLatitude, self.westernmostLongitude, self.easternmostLongitude]
            return NSPredicate(format: "\(latitudeName) >= %@ && \(latitudeName) <= %@ && \(longitudeName) >= %@ && \(longitudeName) <= %@", argumentArray: args)
        }
    }
```