# Set NSSortDescriptor for CoreData using a calculated field

Tags: swift, sorting

I have used an extension to add calculated properties to a CoreData database.  I would like to use an NSSortDescriptor with a FetchRequest to filter and sort the CoreData information based on one of those calculated properties.  The code compiles with no problem and works fine when sorting based on a native CoreData attribute, but the code crashes during execution when trying to apply the NSSortDescriptor based on a calculated field.

Following is a simplified snippet of code taken from my "GameLog+CoreDataProperties.swift" file where the computed property is defined in the extension.  This compiles and runs properly:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension GameLog {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<GameLog> {
        return NSFetchRequest<GameLog>(entityName: "GameLog")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: Date?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var totalPoints: Int32
    @NSManaged public var numberOfGames: Int32

   /* Calculated fields for game statistics */
     @objc dynamic var scorePerGame: Double {
         return Double(totalPoints) / Double(numberOfGames) 
     }

   var wrappedDate: Date {
        date ?? Date()
    }
    var wrappedID: UUID {
        id ?? UUID()
    }
   var wrappedPoints: Int32 {
        totalPoints
    }
    var wrappedNumberOfGames: Int32 {
        numberOfGames
    }
}
```

Following is the snippet of code where I set the NSPredicate and NSSortDescriptor that will be used to filter and sort the data.  This also compiles and runs properly (after I marked the calculated property as "@objc dynamic"):

```
// Set how the results will be filtered and sorted
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())! as NSDate)

switch  self.chosenStats {
case 0:  // Total points
     sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \GameLog.totalPoints, ascending: false)
case 1:  // Games
    sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \GameLog.numberOfGames, ascending: false)
default:  // Points per game
    sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \GameLog.scorePerGame, ascending: false)
}
```

However, when the app is executed and the sort filter is applied, it works fine in the first two cases (where sorting based on a native CoreData attribute), but in the third case (using the NSSortDescriptor based on the calculated property) the app crashes with the dreaded "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error.

Following is the code where I call the view used to do the filtering and sorting:

```
FilteredGameView(filterCriteria: self.predicate, sortCriteria: [self.sortDescriptor])
```

This is the code (simplified) to list the filtered and sorted games.  As noted above, this works perfectly when sorting on native CoreData attributes (case 0 and 1) but not on the calculated property (case 2).

```
import SwiftUI

struct FilteredHOFView: View {

    var filteredGames: FetchRequest<GameLog>

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    init(
        filterCriteria: NSPredicate,
        sortCriteria: [NSSortDescriptor]
    ) {
        self.filteredGames = FetchRequest(
            entity: GameLog.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: sortCriteria,
            predicate: filterCriteria
        )
    }


    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(filteredGames.wrappedValue, id: \.self) { game in
                HStack {
                    Text("Show stats here")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what the problem is?  Is there something special that I need to do in applying the @objc marker?

Comment: What is the reported reason of the crash?

Comment: The first two cases don't get the error, and the only differences that I can see are (1) a native attribute vs. calculated field, and (2) Double vs Int32

Comment: Try to mark the computed property with `@objc dynamic`

Comment: Dude - You're brilliant.  That worked.  THANKS!!!!

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.KeyPath<MyApp.GameLog, Swift.Int32> –

Comment: Hi #vadian - Progress, but still a problem.  Your suggestion made the NSSortDescriptor valid (great!), but now the app crashes with a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error when I apply the NSSortDescriptor for the @objc dynamic calculated property.  It works fine with the native attributes though.  I updated the question to include the fix and add the code I use to call the FetchRequest.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that this is not possible.  A Core Data fetch request cannot sort on a computed property, only on persistent stored properties.  I found the following question that I had previously overlooked on this site.

[Sorting NSFetchedResultsController by Swift Computed Property on NSManagedObjectSubclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131497/sorting-nsfetchedresultscontroller-by-swift-computed-property-on-nsmanagedobject)

However, if anyone knows otherwise, please let me know.