# Core Data/SwiftUI: Sort FetchRequest by a condition (specific items first)

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

**Goal:**

If there is no subscription, I want the ‘free’ items to appear first in a list.

In more generic terms, I want to sort a fetch request using a condition.

**Context:**

I have a list of entities Item stored in Core Data, and display them in a list.

Each element in the list opens a detail view for that item.

However, some items can only be opened with a paid subscription. If there is no subscription, ‘free’ items open, but most of them lead to the paywall.

This is accomplished with a property ‘id’: String? on Item, and a Constants.freeItems: [String] array which stores the ids of ‘free’ items. When an element appears, it checks if its id is contained in the array. If yes, it appears as a ‘free’ item.

**What I tried:**

I tried adding a computed property ‘free’ to Item:

```
@objc var free: Bool {
    Constants.freeItems.contains(id!)
}
```

Then, I could use:

```
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.free, ascending: true)
```

However, this crashes with a message that property ‘free’ was not found. Apparently, sort descriptors do not accept computed properties. As per here, for example: [Set NSSortDescriptor for CoreData using a calculated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974524/set-nssortdescriptor-for-coredata-using-a-calculated-field)

I know I could add a persistent attribute ‘free’ to the Item model, but it seems like significant complexity in reaction to a simple problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since the freeItems array exists outside of Core Data it’s probably better to perform the sorting on the returned result. On the other hand, if the subscription being free or not is an essential piece of information it might be better to add it as a property on your entity as you mention yourself.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.