# Optimizing The Way To Know most nearby objects

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, geolocation, core-location

I'm using Core Location with ios 6 for this.

**Scenario**:

I have the spacial coordinates of a sample of points. I save all those coords using core data.
As and when I am moving with my iphone, I need to detect if I am like 500m from any points in that sample.

Right now, I am looping through those points and calculating the distances of them from my current location. It does this frequently as the user's current location is changing.
But the thing is this will not be a good idea if I have like 100 points, 1000 points.etc

**Question:**

How can I optimize this, any hint?

Comment: Similar questions: [question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833895/find-nearest-by-lat-long-with-core-data),[question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176127/core-data-and-core-location)

Comment: Amar your suggestions are not what I was looking since I already know how to calculate the distance. What I want to know is, is there any optimized way calculate them?

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

- rasterize (grid) your objects and asign each object to a grid-object (clustering).
- while moving, detect the grids intersecting your current position/radius.
- get the most nearby object(s) inside those grids.

So you only need to calculate the distances of your grid-objects and the distances to the objects inside the grid-objects nearby your position.